# How can you prevent a UserControl from being constructed when its parent is rendered?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I've been working to improve scrolling performance for an ItemsControl. Initially each item is a simple row of information and when an item is clicked, a detail UserControl is expanded below the item. I'm trying to eliminate the processing being done on the detail UserControl during scrolling. I eventually achieved this with a CustomControl, but I feel like I must be missing a simpler way to do it using the existing framework controls.

Initially, this detail view was a UserControl with Visibility.Collapsed. I should note that Virtualizing and Recycling are enabled for this ItemsControl. Therefore, scrolling performance was poor since each detail view was being bound to the data as the item scrolled into view, even though the detail was not visible.

I then tried using a ContentPresenter where the Content was bound to a DetailViewModel property and the ContentTemplate was set to a keyed DataTemplate. That DetailViewModel property was initialized to Nothing and then set to the appropriate ViewModel object when the item was clicked. This improved scrolling performance because there was no data binding, but I found that the detail UserControl was still getting constructed for each item, and I presume there was some rendering going on as well.

I eventually got the desired behavior with a custom ContentControl that provides dependency properties for `GatedContentTemplate` and `IsGateOpen`. When `IsGateOpen` goes `True`, the `GatedContentTemplate` is passed to the `ContentTemplate` property and the `Content` is set to the `DataContext` of the control, which causes the content to then get constructed, rendered, and bound.

```
<my:GatedContentControl IsGateOpen="{Binding IsDetailVisible}">
    <my:GatedContentControl.GatedContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <my:DetailUserControl/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </my:GatedContentControl.GatedContentTemplate>
</my:GatedContentControl>
```

I can live with this solution, but it's a little janky, and I wonder if I'm missing some way that WPF intends for this to be done.

Comment: I resolved this very same issue with a very similar solution. Until WPF 4.6 comes out, which features content deferring, I think this is the best solution to this particular problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like I wasn't missing anything and this is a need that Microsoft is addressing in .net 4.6.

The Content Deferral feature is discussed in this video, starting at 26:30.
http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/dotnetConf/2015/WPF-in-46-and-beyond

Thanks for the comment HighCore.

Comment: BTW we need to push and insist for Microsoft to open source and start accepting pull requests for WPF. Maybe not the lower level APIs such as DUCE or MilCore, but these kind of things can definitely get some help from the community.